# Unix - processes using fork()

Tags: linux, unix, process, fork

I am trying to solve a problem but I have no idea what I have to do. Here's the problem:

"Create a parent process that receives from the command line n names of files arg1,arg2,...,argn. The parent creates n-2 child processes. Every child process receives two arguments: i, argi. The argi file will be modified if i>2: remove from the argi file every byte on position multiple of i."

This is what I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
printf("Creating a child\n");
int i;
for(i=0;i<argc-2;i++){
 if(fork()==0){
 printf("CHILD %d!\n",i+1);
 exit(0);
 }
}
wait(0);
}
```

DO you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You will be better off counting the loop from 2 to argc-1 (inclusive).  Since you are doing argc-2 forks, you should have argc-2 waits as well instead of a single wait.  Other than that, you are just reading in a file and writing it back after removing the specified bit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I really don't know how to remove the bytes? I mean, I don't really understand this part "Every child process receives two arguments: i, argi." and the one with the bytes. If you could be more explicit! Thank you! :)

Comment: This will be slightly more complex.  Let us say i == 2.  And let us say your file contains: Hello World.  If you remove all the byte indexed at multiples of 2, you should get HloWrd which is my favored interpretation.  However, an easier thing will remove byte 2, then byte 4 from the output of the previous, and so on.  This will give you: Hll Wrl.  If you want to do the first one, you can simply do it by reading in the file, removing the ith byte (and multiples) and copying them back.

Comment: If you have two strings str (read from file) and str1, the following loop should do: k = 0; for ( j = 0; j < strlen(str); j++ ) { if ( j % i != 0 ){  str1[k] = str[j]; k++ } }